# postman - POST body string interpolation possible?

Tags: postman

I am using postman to develop an API. It works quite well but as my examples become more complex I want to be able to back some message morphing in the body of my message so that each message is unique.

The message body is raw XML. I am trying to interpolate variables into this both within and without enquoted quotes, but I am not having any success.

```
<xml>
  <someelement someattribute="{{someVariable}}"
       >somestring{{nextMessageCounter}}</someelement>
</xml>
```

But.. all I am getting is just the XML with the {{value}} and not the string interpolation.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is the `someVariable` value saved anywhere? In an environment or global variable?

Comment: Environment or global variables dont work either. I get the XML with {{someVariable}} which means string interpolation is not working the way I expected it would.

Comment: Can you post an image of what Postman looks like? There’s no reason for this not to work, from the information you’ve given.

Comment: There are only a few places that those placeholders would be getting the information in a POST request body. A data file from a collection run, a pre-request script and a Collection/Global/Environment variable so if it’s not using one of those ways, something is not quite right in your request.